# Enabling proguard causes crashlytics exception

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, google-fabric

After enabling proguard in my gradle file:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider
```

Funny thing is that it works on android with API26, but it doesn't on API16.
If I open generated **mapping.txt** file I can see this line:

```
com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider -> com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider:
```

Which indicates that crashlytics is not being obfuscated, yet BaseDexClassLoader still can't find it.

My proguard-rules.pro looks like this:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-repackageclasses
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-repackageclasses ''

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

I tried enabling multidex and it solved the problem, but I don't want to have multidex when my project is nowhere near 65k method limit. If I disable proguard, app also works just fine.

Is proguard responsible for increased method count? How to fix this issue without relying on multidex?